# How can you compute $a^b \mod n$ in polynomial time to the length of the input $(a,b,n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know there are efficient methods for modular exponentiation, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what "polynomial" refers to in this case. What's wrong with just computing $x = a^b$ then computing $x \mod n$ directly?

Comment: The size of $a^b$ is $b\,\log\,a$ which is exponential in the size of $b$ (the size of $b$ is $\log\,b$).  Exponential sized outputs require exponential time to compute.

Comment: @DanielV I think this comment would make a better answer than the two below, so maybe you can transform it into one? :)

Comment: @Niklas Thank you, but I would prefer that a full answer include a comparison of modular exponential and exponentiation-then-modulus.  If you want to make a full answer, feel free to copy what I write in it ^_^

Comment: @DanielV: Well I guess it's enough to mention that the multiplications get exponentially expensive in one case (by your argument) and are bounded by $log^2 n$ in the other case. You don't have to obviously, the information is already there anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something can be solved in [polynomial time](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialTime.html), that means that the number of computations grows as fast as $n^x$ for some $x$. This is considered a good property of numerical methods.

The problem with computing $x = a^b$ first is for example if both $a$ and $b$ are huge numbers, for example $a=b=10^{1234567890}$. Using more efficient methods, we don't have to compute the enormous nunber $a^b$ to find out what we really want, which is $a^b \mod{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

The worry if you were to compute $x=a^b$ is that $x$ could be a huge number which would negatively impact the amount of memory used.

Consider this example: Compute $3^{125784356358} \mod 5$. Say you have no knowledge of Fermat's little theorem and can only use the square and multiply method, then first computing $3^{125784356358}$ then taking mod is "suicidial". It is far better to take mod along the way so that the intermediate values are all in the range of $0$ to $4$.

As to your question on "what polynomial refers to?" I would like to refer you to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity